# Invalid verify on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: x => x.AddOrUpdate<tblCustomer>(new[] { It.IsAny<tblCustomer>() })

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, moq

I'm getting this error from Moq, and it doesn't make much in the way of sense to me

Here are my main method that i want to mock

```
public int Add(Customer customer)
    {
        var result = 0;

        using (_entverasysEntities)
        {
            var doesCustExist = _entverasysEntities.tblCustomers.Any(cust => cust.CustomerName.Trim() == customer.CustomerName.Trim() && cust.IsDelete.Value == false);
            if (!doesCustExist)
            {
                customer.CustomerId = Guid.NewGuid();
                customer.CreatedBy = customer.CustomerId;
                customer.UpdatedBy = customer.CustomerId;
                customer.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                customer.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                customer.IsDeleted = false;
                customer.SpaceTypeId = 1;
                _entverasysEntities.tblCustomers.AddOrUpdate(Mapper.Map(customer, new tblCustomer()));
                result = _entverasysEntities.SaveChanges() > 0 ? (int)ReturnResult.Success : (int)ReturnResult.Failure;

                if (result == 1)
                {
                    // will be changed once the Unit Details are finalized 
                    customer.UnitMapping.CustomerId = customer.CustomerId;
                    customer.UnitMapping.CustomerUnitMappingId = Guid.NewGuid();
                    customer.UnitMapping.CreatedBy = customer.CustomerId;
                    customer.UnitMapping.UpdatedBy = customer.CustomerId;
                    customer.UnitMapping.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    customer.UnitMapping.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    _entverasysEntities.tblCustomerUnitMappings.AddOrUpdate(Mapper.Map(customer.UnitMapping, new tblCustomerUnitMapping()));
                    result = _entverasysEntities.SaveChanges() > 0 ? (int)ReturnResult.Success : (int)ReturnResult.Failure;
                }
            }
            else
                result = (int)ReturnResult.RecordExist;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Unit Test

```
[TestMethod]
public void CustomerDataManager_AddCustomerTest()
{

    var custid = Guid.NewGuid();

    var customerData = new List<tblCustomer>
    {
        new tblCustomer {CustomerName="Enterprize",IsDelete=false},

    }.AsQueryable();


    var unitMappingData = new List<tblCustomerUnitMapping>
    {
        new tblCustomerUnitMapping { CustomerId=custid},
    }.AsQueryable();

    var mockContext = new Mock<ENTVERASYSEntities>();
    var mockCustomer = new Mock<DbSet<tblCustomer>>();
    var mockUnitMapping = new Mock<DbSet<tblCustomerUnitMapping>>();


    mockCustomer.As<IQueryable<tblCustomer>>().Setup(x => x.Provider).Returns(customerData.Provider);
    mockCustomer.As<IQueryable<tblCustomer>>().Setup(x => x.Expression).Returns(customerData.Expression);
    mockCustomer.As<IQueryable<tblCustomer>>().Setup(x => x.ElementType).Returns(customerData.ElementType);
    mockCustomer.As<IQueryable<tblCustomer>>().Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(customerData.GetEnumerator());
    mockCustomer.SetReturnsDefault(customerData.GetEnumerator());
    mockCustomer.Verify(x => x.AddOrUpdate(It.IsAny<tblCustomer>()),Times.Once());
    mockContext.Verify(x => x.SaveChanges(),Times.Once());

    mockUnitMapping.As<IQueryable<tblCustomerUnitMapping>>().Setup(x => x.Provider).Returns(unitMappingData.Provider);
    mockUnitMapping.As<IQueryable<tblCustomerUnitMapping>>().Setup(x => x.Expression).Returns(unitMappingData.Expression);
    mockUnitMapping.As<IQueryable<tblCustomerUnitMapping>>().Setup(x => x.ElementType).Returns(unitMappingData.ElementType);
    mockUnitMapping.As<IQueryable<tblCustomerUnitMapping>>().Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(unitMappingData.GetEnumerator());
    //mockUnitMapping.Verify(x => x.AddOrUpdate(new tblCustomerUnitMapping { CustomerId = custid, CustomerName = "Enterprize", CreatedBy = custid, UpdatedBy = custid, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now }));
    //mockContext.Verify(x => x.SaveChanges());


    mockContext.Setup(x => x.tblCustomers).Returns(mockCustomer.Object);
    //mockContext.Setup(x=>x.tblCustomers.AddOrUpdate()).re

    mockContext.Setup(t => t.tblCustomerUnitMappings).Returns(mockUnitMapping.Object);

    var service = new CustomerDataManager(mockContext.Object);


    int service2 = service.Add(new Customer { CustomerId = custid, CustomerName = "Enterprize1" ,CreatedBy=custid,UpdatedBy=custid,CreatedDate=DateTime.Now,UpdatedDate=DateTime.Now,SpaceTypeId=1});

    Assert.AreEqual(2, service2);
    Assert.AreEqual("Enterprize",service2);
    Assert.AreEqual(custid, service2);

}
```

When i debug above test method, this below line throw an exception

```
mockCustomer.Verify(x => x.AddOrUpdate(It.IsAny<tblCustomer>()),Times.Once());
```

The error was

> Invalid verify on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: `x =>
>   x.AddOrUpdate<tbl Customer>(new[] { })`

Not sure how I can fix this, And i am using EF6 with model first approach.

Comment: Moq can only mock virtual members. `AddOrUpdate` is apparently not virtual so it is unable to mock it as stated in the exception message

Comment: so if i set AddorUpdate virtual,then in this case it can work!!

Comment: If you are in control of that class and can update it, then yes

Comment: You are also calling the verify before exercising the test.

Comment: Okay but is there any other option to do mocking easily

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by that. Also is `AddOrUpdate` an extension method? I am not familiar with that member on `DbSet<>`

Comment: i use AddorUpdate as a static method ,In this stage i am not sure what to do, Because i need solution urgently, And i am not able to change my DAL layer

Comment: if `AddOrUpdate` is a static extension method then Moq cannot mock it.

Comment: okay, can i use other mocking technique like rhino mock etc..In that we are using stub and mockRepository

Comment: Show that method. You would have to mock what is done within the extension method if you have control of the class.

Comment: okay thanks for your response..